# How can I delete the kali linux wsl folder on windows?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Kali Linux a while back using the Windows and used a few times to play around with it but a couple days I got another pc and installed Manjaro on it so I could use it full time.

So I tried uninstalling Kali Linux through the **Add or Remove Programs** in Settings and it uninstalled Kali but the problem is that it's still taking space on my disk.

I had **130 GB** before the uninstall and it stayed the same after even though Kali Linux was taking **28 GB** before.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

WSL does not install the Kali App in Programs and Features (at least not on my machines).

Remove the Kali App in Settings, Apps.  That should fully remove it.

You should of course, restart after removing the app.

======

You might, if something has gone wrong, uninstall WSL (Control Panel, Programs and Features, Windows Features).  Uncheck WSL, exit out,restart and then if you wish, enable WSL again)

[image: Kali WSL installed in Apps]

Answer (score 0):

When you install a distribution from the Microsoft Store, two things happen (at a very high level):

- First, the rootfs for the distribution (`install.tar.gz`) and the executables for installing it are installed.
- When you run the "app" for the first time, it creates the actual WSL distribution using that rootfs.  It also asks for the default username/password so that it can create your user.

When you *uninstall* the Store App, what is removed is simply the rootfs and installer.  Your distribution is still installed, as you can see with `wsl -l -v`.  This follows the guidance if you go to the "Advanced Options" for the app in your Settings.  Under the "Uninstall" option, it says "Your documents will not be affected."

This wasn't always the case, in my experience.  Originally, when a WSL distribution (at least Ubuntu) was uninstalled, it removed all files with it.  Given the wording of the Help, this was unexpected to some users.

To remove the distribution *filesystem*, you can run:

```
# Warning: DESTRUCTIVE operation
# Substitute your distribution name below (from wsl -l -v)

wsl --unregister kali-linux
```

That should recover the additional disk space.